# Plupload sends data with wrong MIME on Android 2.x

Tags: javascript, plupload

I have a problem in getting plupload to work on Android 2.x devices. Only on these devices plupload sends the file as **binary/octet** MIME type, although it should send **multipart/form-data** as it does on other systems (desktop chrome, FF, Android 3.x and 4.x). So the server simply fails to process these requests.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,silverlight,html4',
    silverlight_xap_url : settings.url_silverlight,
    browse_button : 'pickfiles',
    container : 'uploader',
    max_file_size : '3mb',
    url : settings.url_nailarts,
    filters : [
        {title : NF.T("img_files"), extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"}
    ], ... });
```

multipart: true is default, but it does not help even if I put it explicitly in there. What can I do? Where is the problem?
 Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm.. must be a bug in the android browser. Possibly somehow it handles the post of data.

Comment: yes, that is what I thought. I have tried it on Firefox mobile and everything works as it should!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I've tried with dolphin mini browser on android 2.3. and it sends application/octet-stream instead of multipart/form-data. I am using plupload v.1.5.7. Is there any solution for this except changing browser?

Answer (score 0):

Andorid 2.x doesn't send multipart/form-data. Instead, it sends the file in the body, thus application/octet-stream is the correct type.

On your server, you'll need to handle this case by saving the stream itself.